# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'month' Process finished with exit code 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Python code**

```
import pandas as pd import numpy as np import os

RD = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/acharbha/Desktop/fullbackup_success/python/raw_Data_success_Rate.csv")

NEW = {"Cell": RD['Cell'], "LastFullResult": RD["LastFullResult"], "LastFullStartTime": RD["LastFullStartTime"],
       "status code": RD["status code"]} NEW = pd.DataFrame(NEW) date = pd.datetime.now() NEW_LastFullStartTime = []

for date1 in NEW.LastFullStartTime:
    if isinstance(date1.month, int):
        if date1.month == date.month:
            NEW_LastFullStartTime.append("True")
        else:
            NEW_LastFullStartTime.append("False")
    else:
        NEW_LastFullStartTime.append("NaN") NEW["NEW_LastFullStartTime"] = pd.Series(NEW_LastFullStartTime) NEW = NEW.drop("LastFullStartTime", axis=1)

Oct_Full_ran_failed_not_completed_yet = NEW[(NEW["LastFullResult"] == "Failure") &
                                            (NEW["NEW_LastFullStartTime"] == "True") & (NEW["status code"] >= 1)] Oct_Full_not_ran_yet = NEW[(NEW["NEW_LastFullStartTime"] == "False") | (NEW["NEW_LastFullStartTime"] == "NaN")] Oct_full_ran_successful = NEW[(NEW["LastFullResult"] == "Success") & (NEW["NEW_LastFullStartTime"] == "True")]

result = Oct_full_ran_successful.groupby('Cell').count() result = result.drop(result.columns[[1, 2]], axis=1) Oct_full_ran_successful = result.rename(columns={"LastFullResult": "Oct_full_ran_successful"}) d3 = Oct_full_ran_successful

Oct_Full_not_ran_yet.groupby('Cell').count() result = Oct_Full_not_ran_yet.groupby('Cell').count() result = result.drop(result.columns[[1, 2]], axis=1) Oct_Full_not_ran_yet = result.rename(columns={"LastFullResult": "Oct_Full_not_ran_yet"}) d2 = Oct_Full_not_ran_yet

Oct_Full_ran_failed_not_completed_yet.groupby('Cell').count() result = Oct_Full_ran_failed_not_completed_yet.groupby('Cell').count() result = result.drop(result.columns[[1, 2]], axis=1) Oct_Full_ran_failed_not_completed_yet = result.rename(
    columns={"LastFullResult": "Oct_Full_ran_failed_not_completed_yet"})

d1 = Oct_Full_ran_failed_not_completed_yet d2 = pd.merge(d1,d2, on=['Cell'], how ='outer')

result = pd.merge(d2, d3, on=['Cell'], how='outer') print(result)
```

**Error:**

```
*C:\Users\acharbha\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/acharbha/PycharmProjects/Python_class/Intel/Success_Rate/success_rate.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/acharbha/PycharmProjects/Python_class/Intel/Success_Rate/success_rate.py", line 25, in <module>
    if isinstance(date1.month, int):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'month'
Process finished with exit code 1*
```

csv input sample:

[image]

1. Oct Full ran, failed & not completed yet: Oct full ran, failed & not
   completed yet means –  “LastFullStartTime” – contains current month 
   date and non-empty  && “LastFullResult” – Failed                        && “status
   code” – greater than 1

   2. Oct Full not ran yet:
         Oct Full not ran means – “LastFullStartTime” - empty or date older    than current month
   3. Oct full ran successful – Oct full ran successful means – “LastFullStartTime” – contains current month date             &&
      “LastFullResult” – success
   4. Grand Total Grand Total means – Count of BackupPolicyID for each distinct cell; should be ideally equal to above 3 columns
      (1+2+3=4)
   5. Success rate for full ran in Oct Success rate for full ran in Oct means – Above column1/(column1+column3) in percentage
   6. Success rate of full backup Success rate of full backup means – Above column1/(column1+column2+ column3) in percentage
   7. Percentage of backup coverage Percentage of backup coverage means – Above (column1+column3)/column4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add some more explanation to what you are doing. Without guessing, we can tell you only what the error message already tells you: you are trying to get the `month` attribute of the `date1` variable, in your loop.

My only guess would be to convert the data to date type somehow, but this might also fail, as I don't know what the values look like in `RD["LastFullStartTime"]`.

You could change this line, adding the converter `pd.to_datetime()`:

```
NEW = {"Cell": RD['Cell'], "LastFullResult": pd.to_datetime(RD["LastFullResult"]), "LastFullStartTime": RD["LastFullStartTime"], "status code": RD["status code"]}
NEW = pd.DataFrame(NEW)
date = pd.datetime.now()
NEW_LastFullStartTime = []
```

Comment: pd.to_datetime() has helped